# jQuery go to hash without reload

Tags: jquery, hash, anchor

I'm building a webpage which requires no page reload when I browse (I use ajax/php to achieve that).

When I browse items (lots of them) and open one of them - I want page to return to the last place in page when I close the page.

I use anchors to achieve that.

My code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.content', function() {

  ... some other code ...


  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/includes/content.php',
    data: info,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result){

        if(type == 'close') {
            window.location.hash = '#' + hash;
            location.reload();
        }


    }
  });


return false;
});
```

Problem is: jQuery does add a hash to the url, but page doesnt jump to specified place in page. location.reload(); does do that, but I require NO page load.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Are any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: Missing code is just a bunch of variables set.

Comment: Should window.location.hash = '#hash' actually jump to anchor or it just sets anchor in url?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scroll to a specified place you can animate `html`,`body`

```
$('html, body').animate({
   scrollTop: $("#myDiv").offset().top
}, 2000);
```